# How to Create a zipfiles from source file (Google Drive) in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I have a problem with Google Collaboratory, which is making an archive file in zip form with the source file directly from Google Drive.

How do you enter the code into Google Colab?

I have searched on [docs.phyton.org](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html?highlight=zipfile#cmdoption-zipfile-l) with the following information:

> 13.5.4.1. Command-line options
>   -l  List files in a zip file.
>
> -c   ...  Create zipfile from source files.
>
> -e   Extract zipfile into target directory.
>
> -t  Test whether the zip file is valid or not.

But when I tried Google Colab, the code was error. it said:

```
<ipython-input-6-a3cce7dbe6bc> in <module> ()
----> 1 -c <zipfile> "/ content / drive / My Drive ......
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Comment: Your English is better than most, no need to excuse it :) This doesn't seem to be about programming though?

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow. it could be about Programming. Previously I just entered the code but it even disappeared when I posted the question